# How can I make a clipping mask on an image in shape of a triangle in CSS or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, svg, raphael, vml

The clipping mask has to be in a shape of a triangle facing down and only de right part is showing.The left part of the triangle mask is not important.How could I make this?

Answer (score 1):

For Webkit you can use a [clipping mask](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) via CSS. However, this won't work for [Firefox or IE or Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask-clip).

For modern browsers, you can use SVG with a [clipping path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath). Here is an example of [clipping an image in SVG](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Clipping_and_Masking#svgess-CHP-9-EX-6).

Comment: Well it seems that the raphael.js does the job.But sadly I can't move the fill image in VML as I would move a background image with background-position.The clipping is perfect though.